# Custom Error Message MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

Working on Project which is mixture of ASP.Net Web Forms & MVC.

Scenario : In an Web Form application , part of an page is rendering using MVC Partial View as shown below image.

[image]

In Web Form **aspx** page , have defined an Div with ID = MVCPartialView1 and using Jquery Ajax successfully can bind the returned Partial View to Web Form.

```
 $.ajax(
 {
 success: function (msg) { $("#MVCPartialView1").html(msg); }
});
```

For Handling Error Scenario made use of the following code.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public sealed class ErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            // Execute the normal exception handling routine
            base.OnException(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "CustomError.aspx"
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Base Controller :

```
[ErrorAttribute]
public class BaseController : Controller
```

Actual Problem is when an any exception occurred inside MVC Partial View ( Controller ) , CustomError is displayed only inside `DIV MVCPartialView1` but it would make sense to show CustomError as full Contain of `WebForm.aspx`

[image]

**But Expected CustomError Message is :**

[image]

Comment: Why are you mixing MVC & Web Forms? Out of curiosity.

Comment: It's an existing Project which is already in Web Forms. Slowly we are migrating towards MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work only with js in your scenario.

Some thing like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
   success: function (msg) 
   {
      if(msg.indexOf("Error") > -1) //You should check if Error page returned
      {
         window.location.href = "CustomError.aspx"; //Here if redirect to error of full page
      }
      else
      {
        $("#MVCPartialView1").html(msg); 
      }   
   }
});
```

Comment: Yep i guess this is the only way of doing it.